# Does an Inflammable Psycho burn?

Tags: borderlands-2

Krieg has some interesting new skills, including the Hellborn tree that revolves around setting yourself on fire.

What happens if I am wearing an inflammable shield like [image]

Since I would be immune to burn damage, would I still catch fire from self immolating skills?  If so, would I burn but take no damage? Or does self conflagrating ignore damage reduction?

Comment: [Inflammable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inflammable) actually means "burns easily," contrary to popular belief.

Comment: Inflammable means flammable? What a country!

Comment: As a pyro, you'd do well to know the proper terminology, though it's not like anyone would understand you anyway ;)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nO3Wfenv4Mo

Comment: When I read the title `Does an inflammable Psycho burn?` I thought "*obvious downvote candidate*". Then I read the question and realized, that you were using the wrong word xD

Comment: I know that flammable and inflammable are synonymous. The title was just a setup for a Simpson's joke in the comments :)  Also, if you look at the linked shield, the Inflammable prefix on shields gives complete immunity to burn damage.

Comment: @Kexlox Ah, ok. I just submitted a suggested edit to the title. Feel free to reject the suggestion then.

Comment: @Kelox: Those bandits never were too good with words.

Comment: Related: [(from EL&U SE) Why are not “infamous” and “inflammable” the opposite of “famous” and “flammable”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1578/9290)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your shield has an 'Inflammable' prefix, you won't catch fire and take damage from burning, even from the Hellborn skill tree.

It seems to be corroborated by these various posts from the Gearbox Software Borderlands 2 forums:

> Don't use anything labeled 'Inflammable' you will not catch fire.

<sup>Source: [Chance to burn vs. resists?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310075635/http://oldforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=283285)</sup>

> Inflammable cancels it all out, but a shield that reduces fire damage should still work.

<sup>Source: [Hellborn and Shields](https://web.archive.org/web/20150313041753/http://oldforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=283624)</sup>

> I did have the 'Inflammable' but that renders most of that tree useless if I can't set myself on fire.

<sup>Source: [I Hate Burning](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=4138711&postcount=4)</sup>

> Q: Can you still light yourself on fire with an inflammable shield? A: Tested and no. Wouldn't be enough of a "risk/reward" system if you could.

<sup>Source: [Can you still light yourself on fire with an inflammable shield?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310072621/http://oldforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=282095)</sup>

> ...from what limited testing I've been able to do so far, inflammable shields prevent you from getting the bonuses associated with being on fire.

<sup>Source: [Inflammable Shields and Hellborn](https://web.archive.org/web/20150309015910/http://oldforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=281922)</sup>

> Inflammable does not work, since you can't get lit on fire.
>
> No, it won't work, inflammable mod nullifies the self ignite thus making the hellborn skills bonuses not work.

<sup>Source: [Does the 'Inflammable' prefix work with Hellborn?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310072702/http://oldforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=281740)</sup>

> From my playing with an inflammable shield I'd have to say it prevents you from ever self igniting.

<sup>Source: [Inflammable shields hindering Hellborn?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310080514/http://oldforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=281221)</sup>

Comment: Ok then, guess I don't need to save this 61 Inflammable for when I get my psycho up there.  Shame :)

Comment: Now I'll have to find out what happens with an adaptive shield > 50% and level 5 numbed nerves... i.e. fire resist > 100%

Comment: @Kexlox [One of the posts above](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=283624) mention that adaptive (and non-Inflammable) shields will allow the Hellborn skill tree's burn effects, but will lessen the fire damage.

Comment: I can confirm that you don't take damage ... and I'm pretty sure I've ignited myself (but it's subtle, as you don't start taking damage, and I wasn't in 3rd player camera angles) ... but I hadn't thought to test if I wasn't actually getting the bonuses ... doh.  (and I haven't plaid for more than a week, so it's possible they patched it since then)