# Will an item that gives 'fire resistance' lessen the damage that Krieg the Psycho gets from self-immolation?

Tags: borderlands-2

I got a [Skin of the Ancients](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Skin_of_the_Ancients) relic that has a 'Fire Resistance +26.1%' effect: 
[image]

If I'm playing as Krieg the Psycho and spec'ed into the [Hellborn](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Hellborn) skill tree, will I get less fire/burn damage if I set myself on fire with this relic equipped?

What about adaptive shields like the [Neogenator](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Neogenator) or [Evolution](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Evolution)? Will setting one's self on fire trigger the adaptive shields to resist fire element damage? Will it lessen the fire/burn damage I get if I set myself on fire?

This [post from the Gearbox Software forums](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=4129606&postcount=9) state that "*the adaptive shield does help reduce the [burn] effect*." Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: not sure if this is an exact dupe, but the answer is already part of the other question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117897/does-an-inflammable-psycho-burn

Comment: which amusingly enough, you posted the answer to :P

Comment: @spartacus That [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/117897/4797) talks about an 'Inflammable' shield (gives 100% immunity to burn damage). I'm talking about items here that only partially resist fire damage.

Comment: your own comment attached to your answer: `One of the posts above mention that adaptive (and non-Inflammable) shields will allow the Hellborn skill tree's burn effects, but will lessen the fire damage`  Joe also confirmed it in the comments section.

Comment: @spartacus That comment was a reply to another comment about adaptive shields, not the question itself - that's why I didn't include it in the answer. Also, the info is from only one source, so I am not too sure of it. I asked about adaptive shields too to confirm it here. I'm also talking about relics that resist fire elemental damage here, not just adaptive shields. Inflammable shields are not the same as adaptive shields (which just partially resist elemental damage). What Joe confirmed was about 'Inflammable' shields.

Comment: fair enough, like I said i wasn't entirely sure if it was worthy of a close dupe.

Comment: I've played Hellborn Krieg for 35 levels and worn Adaptive shields, but I was so mad I never checked my resistance :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. I used to take 50 damage a second without a relic. with it (50% fire damage reduction) I only take 20 damage a second.

Comment: It's a very good relic :P